# How do I drive 4 motors from a single L293D?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, dc-motor

I have 4 DC motors, and I do not need to individually control each of them. Can I connect all the motors parallely to one pair of motor pins on the L293D? Does this pose any issues?

I'm using BO geared motors with the following specs:
    RPM - 100;
    Output Torque - 0.8--5kgcm;
    Operating Voltage - 3v-12v;
    No-load Current - 57 mA;

Comment: If they are high voltage very low current tiny micro-motors, ok but not likely work if DCR of coil is near Rce of transistors resulting in huge voltage drop on L293D

Comment: You need to add some detail about your DC motors if you want an answer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I have added that information.